# When integral becomes from b to a , but not a to b ?

Tags: integration

I just saw a proof on $ \int_a^bf(x) dx= \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$

One of the proof is using change of variables: $a+b-x=t, dx=-dt$, and
$$ \int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=-\int_b^af(t)dt = \int_a^bf(t)dt$$

May I know how the middle integral: $-\int_b^af(t)dt$ , becomes $\int_b^a$ ? Why it doesn't stay $\int_a^b$ Since we are just replacing the variable I thought?

Comment: $t=a+b-x$ is $b$ when $x=a$ and $a$ when $x=b$. When you change variables you have to replace the limits with the limits in terms of the new variable.

Comment: Thanks!! I understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

You substitute $a+b-x=t$. Therefore you have to insert the initial values $x$ to get the new values $t$. See also Ian's comment.

Note that the order matters. If you exchange the lower and the upper value, the integral changes its sign. This is used in the last step of the proof.

Further note that the derivate of $a+b-x$ is $-1$, so we have $dt=-dx$ implying $dx=-dt$, therefore the minus-sign.